# Counting values in several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
            KPI_01 KPI_02 KPI_03
date                            
2015-05-24   green  green    red
2015-06-24  orange    red    NaN
```

And I want to count the number of colors for each date in order to obtain:

```
value       green  orange  red
date                          
2015-05-24      2       0    1
2015-06-24      0       1    1
```

Here is my code that does the job. Is there a better way (shorter) to do that ?

```
# Test data
df= pd.DataFrame({'date': ['05-24-2015','06-24-2015'],
             'KPI_01': ['green','orange'],
             'KPI_02': ['green','red'],
             'KPI_03': ['red',np.nan]
             })
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Transforming to long format
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date'])

# Pivoting data
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(long, index='date', columns=['value'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
# Dropping unnecessary level
pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `apply` `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts,axis=1).fillna(0)
            green  orange  red
date                          
05-24-2015      2       0    1
06-24-2015      0       1    1
```

`apply` tends to be slow, and row-wise operations slow as well, but to be honest if your frame isn't very big you might not even notice the difference.

Comment: My `DataFrame` is not big. I will use this solution tanks !